# How to get max value or last value for default rating setting column in SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint

I want latest rating count value for default ratting setting column instead of average count. How can 
i achieve this by using out of box settings or by customization..? Thanks in advance.

I want **Rating Value(0-5) of last user** who rated the specific document/Image instead of average rating value. 
Number of Ratings provide the count for users who had rated the document..

Answer (score 0):

when you enable ratings on any list or library, the two Site Columns that gets added to the SharePoint list are:

1. Rating - which provides the average rating
2. Number of Ratings- Which provides the rating count.

**Number of ratings** field will provide the latest count value

Comment: Thanks for replay, but i want Rating Value(0-5) of last user who rated the specific document/Image instead of average rating value. 
Number of Ratings provide the count for users who had rated the document..